# How to use a Sprite class with CGRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite

I am very new to programming (especially objective-C) and would like to know how to move a sprite in the form of a drawn CGRect. I am having trouble drawing the CGRect, and get majorly stuck when I try to move the CGRect. Here is my code so far. There is a sprite class (objective-C UIView subclass), and a view controller in this code. All this code shows is how I drew my CGRect. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
//the Sprite.h file

@interface Sprite : UIView {
    UIImage* image;
}

//the Sprite.m file

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, loadedImage.size.width, loadedImage.size.height);  
    self = [super initWithFrame:rect];
    image = [loadedImage retain];
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [image drawInRect:rect];
}

//the ViewController.m file

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // add a sprite
    Sprite* mySprite = [[Sprite alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, 0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:mySprite];
}

//the ViewController.h file

@class Sprite; 

@interface Sprite2TestViewController : UIViewController {
    Sprite* Sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two point

1> you haven't write

```
`if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))`
```

in your init method you should write it

2> The line

```
Sprite* mySprite = [[Sprite alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, 0, 0)];
```

you have given x = 150 y = 100 and height and width is 0... I think you swap it by mistake... you image's height and image's width is 0 right now...